# How can I make this cleaner or smaller?

Tags: urls, user-roles

This code works, but it's going to get huge!
I have 150 "a href" to make and this is going to get rough, lol

Each role has a custom url.

> How can I make this cleaner or smaller?

```
    if ( ! function_exists( 'add_extra_item_to_nav_menu' ) ){

    global $user_ID;

    function add_extra_item_to_nav_menu( $items, $args ) {
       if (current_user_can('administrator') && is_user_logged_in() && $args->menu-5) {
         $items .= '<li><a href="/product-category/public/SCHOOL_NAME-A/" class="navShopNow fungula">SHOP NOW ADMIN</a></li>';
       }
 
       // School ROLEABC
       elseif (current_user_can('ROLEABC') && is_user_logged_in && $args->menu-5) {
         $items .= '<li><a href="/product-category/public/SCHOOL_NAME-B/" class="navShopNow fungula">SHOP NOW ABC</a></li>';
       }
       // School ROLEXYZ
       elseif (current_user_can('ROLEXYZ') && is_user_logged_in && $args->menu-5) {
         $items .= '<li><a href="/product-category/public/SCHOOL_NAME-C/" class="navShopNow fungula">SHOP NOW XYZ</a></li>';
       }
 
       return $items;
    }
 
   add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_extra_item_to_nav_menu', 150, 2 );
 }
```

Comment: Nope, because it's exactly the same code.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/404936/edit) to clarify what the problem is. You say you have 150 links; are you concerned about building 150 `if /elseif` for your roles? Are the links and the roles consistent (eg, it's 150 links of the format `/product-category/public/{school name}` and the `school name` always matches with the same role)?

Comment: this is more like a PHP question, but use e.g. array of arrays and loop over it with foreach and check, if user is logged in and the menu argument, early and only once, etc

Comment: Alternately, since you've already asked a question about this, you might be further ahead to [edit that question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/404883/edit) instead, and provide detail on a) what you need to accomplish and b) where you're having problems.

Comment: ps 150 items might not be a good fit for a menu wrt the user experience.

Comment: Hey, thanks for writing...